# Aircrack-ng, using airmon-ng to change to monitor mode

Tags: aircrack-ng

I've followed this tutorial on installing aircrack on Ubuntu 14.04:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdvGZlUzfRs&src_vid=OF0UjeoTXoI&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_1882595149

I had to tweak a few things to get it to download successfully, but here is what I'm having issues with (and what I can't find a solution for):

This command:

```
sudo airodump-ng mon0
```

of which I get the error:

```
Interface mon0:  
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

The command iwconfig shows:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"nameofmynetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.765 GHz  Access Point: 05:B1:51:42:A1:5D   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Regarding mon0, what is it? I tried some solutions, such as killing processes and updating to the latest aircrack, but I still receive an error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's conceivable that you have a wireless card that simply can't be put in monitor mode - at least with its Linux drivers. Such cards aren't all that common but they certainly exist. Unfortunately, if you have one, the only thing you can do about it is to replace it.

Comment: hey, could you please mark my answer as valid, @boop? thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

you don't need to use *airmon-ng* at all. you can simply:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

than go on with

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
```

and finally

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

thats basically what airmon-ng does.

Comment: It says: Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

Comment: that most likely means that you need to patch your driver - it doesnt support monitor mode.

it may also be that your wirelesscard doesnt support monitor-mode hardware-wise - in which case buying an atheros-wifi-stick is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about how to use `aircrack-ng`.

The command you executed, `sudo airodump-ng mon0`, tells your computer to start capturing packets on the interface called `mon0`, but you don't have that interface yet, that's why it tells you `No such device`.

The general steps in using `aircrack-ng` is:

1. `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`

   - This puts your wireless interface into monitor mode, which is the mode where you can capture all packets, even if they weren't directed to your computer. What the command actually does is it creates another interface called `mon0`, which you can see when you do `iwconfig`. This is the command that you probably didn't execute. If you did run it but you can't see `mon0` afterwards, let us know what was the command's output.
2. `sudo airodump-ng <options> mon0`

   - This starts capturing packets.
3. `sudo aireplay-ng <options> mon0`

   - You use this to attempt to increase the number of IVs being captured so you can easily crack the password.
4. `sudo aircrack-ng <options> <file>`

   - This is the application that then cracks the capture you took to extract the password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output for sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 is this: http://pastebin.com/FjPyvcpg

Comment: Are you sure that was the command you did? Did you do `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0mon`?  Please give us the complete output of `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0; iwconfig`.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure, here's the pastebin image of the output for the command you asked for: http://pastebin.com/KNHrCXBV

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the name of the interface. Use the following commands:

Start your wireless interface in monitoring mode

```
airmon-ng
```

Kill all the interfering processes

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

Instead of `airodump-ng mon0`, type this `airodump-ng wlan0mon`

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: For me it didn't, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From what i've seen, in the latest ubuntu version (15.10) there is a problem when enabling monitor mode on mon0.

To do it clean and clear, use this command to kill any process that can cause problems `sudo airmon-ng check kill` , then use this command to enable monitor mode on mon0 `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` .

Now you can use mon0 with other *-ng commands.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all let's start with killing all processes with `sudo airmon-ng check kill` , then enabling monitor mode with `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` , now the answer to your question is in the output of this command. Notice that it says in the bottom *(experimental wl monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]**prism0**)* for me it says **prism0** this is the interface that was created for me when I used the `airmon-ng start wlan0` command which is in general called mon0 but it's not always the same so you need to check the name of the one that was created for you and use it in the next command. For example in my case, to start capturing packets I will type `airodump-ng prism0` not **mon0**. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

if airodump-ng mon0 doesnt works for you;
give the previous one command as; "airmon-ng start wlp3s0" rather than "airmon-ng start wlan0" because wlan0 works for network on lan and wlp3s0 works for wireless network and then insert command "airodump-ng mon0"
this will surely work for you too