# Wireless down and can't connect

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new and learning some things like wifi hacking (for educational purposes) and after I ran this command on terminal:

`sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 up`

I disconnected on the internet and can't see the wireless networks list.
How do I connect to the internet?

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/549026/37165) has several answers, which may be useful. Not sure why you include `up` in the `airmon-ng` command, because that belongs to `ifconfig`.

Comment: Tried those solutions, but still not working for me. I ran this command: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`but an ERROR appeared `No such device`

Comment: @clearkimura I finally got it, even though I don't know how I solve it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it worked, I ran these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

The first time, it didn't work.
I think I rebooted my pc then tried it again and then it worked.